# Plugin's admin dashboard components not showing up after registering Gutenberg block

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a basic plugin that will create both admin dashboard as well as a Gutenberg block. I first started with creating the admin side and it was working perfectly fine as I followed Wordpress's tutorial [here][1]. But then when I registered a block, the admin page is showing up but no React component which only include an input field.

This is my folder structure with only admin side (no block):

```
my-plugin
  -- build
  -- src
    -- admin
       adminIndex.js
      -- stylesheet
         style.css
      -- components
        -- SomeComponent.js
    index.js
  plugin.php
  package.json
```

`adminIndex.js` file looks like this:

```
import { render }                   from '@wordpress/element';
import App                          from './components/App/App';

window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function () {
        render(
            <App />,
            document.querySelector( '#my-plugin' )
        );
    },
    false
);
```

And this is what `plugin.php` file looks like without block:

```
class MY_PLUGIN{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'menu_item' ] );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'load_admin_scripts' ] );
    }

    public function menu_item() {
        add_menu_page(
            'My Plugin',
            'My Plugin',
            'manage_options',
            'my-plugin',
            ' 
               <h2>Pages</h2>
               <div id="my-plugin"></div>
            ',
            'dashicons-schedule',
            3
        );
    }

    public function load_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
        // Load only on ?page=my-plugin
        if ( 'toplevel_page_my-plugin' !== $hook ) {
            return;
        }

        // Automatically load imported dependencies and assets version.
        $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php';

        // Enqueue CSS dependencies.
        foreach ( $asset_file['dependencies'] as $style ) {
             wp_enqueue_style( $style );
        }

        // Load our app.js.
        wp_register_script(
             'my-plugin',
             plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
             $asset_file[ 'dependencies' ],
             $asset_file[ 'version' ]
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin' );

        // Load our style.css.
        wp_register_style(
             'my-plugin',
             plugins_url( 'src/admin/stylesheet/style.css', __FILE__ ),
             array(),
             $asset_file[ 'version' ]
         );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
    }
}
```

Up until this point the app works and the admin page and the react component is showing up. After this I tried adding a block and this is how the folder structure looks like:

```
my-plugin
  -- build
  -- src
    -- admin
       adminIndex.js
      -- stylesheet
         style.css
      -- components
        -- SomeComponent.js
    -- blocks
       -- block-1
          block.json
          edit.js
          blockIndex.js
          save.js
          editor.scss
          style.scss
    index.js
  plugin.php
  package.json
```

`index.js` file is the import of both of those admin and block index files:

```
import './admin/adminIndex.js
import './blocks/block-1/blockIndex.js';
```

And in `plugin.php` file I registered the block with this:

```
add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'register_blocks' ] );

public function register_blocks() {
     register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/block-1' );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with `enqueuing` scripts above? Admin page worked perfectly fine until i registered a block. Seems like the build is giving the block more priority. Someone please help.

UPDATED

This is how the build folder looks like:

build
blocks
block-1
block.json
index.asset.php
index.css
index.css.map
index.js
index.js.map
style-index.css
style-index.css.map

```
  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/data-basics/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like both your admin and block scripts are being built into the same index.js file in the build directory. This could be causing conflicts. You could try configuring your build process to output separate files for the admin and block scripts.

In your register_blocks function, you could try enqueuing the block script separately using wp_enqueue_script. This would ensure that the block script is only loaded when needed, and not on the admin page. Here's an example:

```
public function register_blocks() {
    // Register the block script
    wp_register_script(
        'my-block',
        plugins_url( 'build/block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/block.js' )
    );

    // Register the block
    register_block_type( 'my-plugin/block-1', array(
        'editor_script' => 'my-block',
    ) );
}
```

Make sure that the path you're providing to register_block_type is correct. If the path is incorrect, the function could be failing silently, causing the block script not to be enqueued. In the example above, I've used a string slug ('my-plugin/block-1') instead of a path for the block name. This is the recommended way to register blocks according to the https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/ Handbook.

**Hi, thanks for your response. Do I keep load_admin_scripts's wp_register_script path build/index.js as it is? What should I point it to?
Reply:**

If you have separated your build files into admin.js and block.js as suggested, you should update the wp_register_script in load_admin_scripts to point to the admin.js file. Here's how you can do it:

```
public function load_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
     if ( 'toplevel_page_my-plugin' !== $hook ) {
        return;
     }
     $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/admin.asset.php';
     foreach ( $asset_file['dependencies'] as $style ) {
         wp_enqueue_style( $style );
     }
     wp_register_script(
         'my-plugin',
         plugins_url( 'build/admin.js', __FILE__ ),
         $asset_file[ 'dependencies' ],
         $asset_file[ 'version' ]
     );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin' );
     wp_register_style(
         'my-plugin',
         plugins_url( 'src/admin/stylesheet/style.css', __FILE__ ),
         array(),
         $asset_file[ 'version' ]
     );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
}
```

I've changed build/index.js to build/admin.js in the plugins_url function. This assumes that your build process outputs admin.js in the build directory. You'll need to adjust this to match your actual build process and directory structure.

**Remember to also update the path in the include function to match the new asset file for your admin script (admin.asset.php).**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Do I keep `load_admin_scripts`'s `wp_register_script` path `build/index.js` as it is? What should I point it to?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the op. It's not working as you suggested. The build folder only contains files for block-1. Check OP updated section for build folder structure.

Comment: There is no admin.js in build folder

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer please take a look.

Comment: Bro there is no admin related files in the build folder

Comment: Enqueue the block script separately: In your register_blocks function, you could try enqueuing the block script separately using wp_enqueue_script. This would ensure that the block script is only loaded when needed, and not on the admin page.

Comment: Check the console for errors: If there are any issues with your scripts, they should show up in the browser console. Check there for any error messages that could help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Check the order of your imports: In your index.js file, you're importing the admin script before the block script. If there are any conflicts between the two, this could be causing the block script to overwrite the admin script. Try switching the order of the imports to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have enqueued the script as you suggested in register block function. The block is working fine. I have two errors in admin side console: 1 is saying that `build/adminIndex.js` is not found and 2 is block title related, which is not importan for now. 

In `index.js` file I now only have adminIndex.js import as block is working without it.

Comment: Which tool are you using for your build process like Webpack or Parcel?

Comment: Make sure that the path in your import statement in index.js matches the actual location of adminIndex.js. If the path is incorrect, the build process won't be able to find the file.

Comment: Build process is what Wordpess comes with by default. Webpack I guess. I haven't touched any of those. Regarding the path, it is fine. I feel like it is not possible to have both admin dashboard and blocks in React. If my plugin has blocks in React, then I guess I have to code admin page in PHP.

Comment: Many of your 8 answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Even your comments here look to be AI-generated. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting quality, non-AI content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.